# closest('tr') not working with Jeditable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am using the plugin Jeditable and do not understand why all the parameters are not in the request.

HTML before rendering:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($liste_eleve_note as $eleve_note)
    <tr data-user-id="{{{ $eleve_note->id_personne }}}">
        <td>{{{ $eleve_note->nom }}}&nbsp;{{{ $eleve_note->prenom }}}</td>
        <td class="edit_area" >{{{ $eleve_note->note_num }}}</td>
        <td class="edit_area" >{{{ $eleve_note->appreciation }}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-user-id="3">
        <td>HACKETT&nbsp;Steve</td>
        <td class="edit_area" >22.00</td>
        <td class="edit_area" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-user-id="106">
        <td>BRUFFORD&nbsp;Bill</td>
        <td class="edit_area" >0.00</td>
        <td class="edit_area" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-user-id="107">
        <td>LENNON&nbsp;John</td>
        <td class="edit_area" ></td>
        <td class="edit_area" ></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.edit_area').editable($('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/edit_note_epreuve', {
    indicator : 'Saving...',
    tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
    onblur : 'submit',
    submitdata : {  
        'user_id'       : $(this).closest('tr').data('user-id'),
        'id_epreuve'    : $('#id_epreuve').val(),
        '_token'        : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr( 'content' )
    },
    onerror : function(settings,original,xhr) {
        alert("It wasn't possible to edit. Try again");
        console.log("XHR Status: " + xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

The request sent to the server:

[image]

The parameter `user_id` is missing. We have the parameters `id` and `value` which are automatically added by the plugin, and we have the parameters `_token` and `id_epreuve` which have been added by the JavaScript.

But not the parameter `user_id`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "*My HTML code:*" - that's not (only) HTML; what does the HTML look like when that script has finished working with it?

Comment: I added the final html. I do not see anything wich could explained the problem.

Comment: `this` (in your `submitdata` object) doesn't mean what you (almost certainly) want it to,. I think you're expecting it to be "the thing that was edited", but it's actually run immediately when the handler is set up, so it's the context in which `.editable()` is called. It's most likely `window`, so `$(this).closest('tr')` isn't going to match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `$(this).closest('tr').data('user-id')` expects `this` to be set to the `td.edit_area` you’re calling `editable()` on… but as written, you’re using whatever `this` is when you make the `$('.edit_area').editable()` call. If `this` is outside your `<tr>` tag, `closest()` won’t find `data-user-id`, which may exclude it from the post.

This may fix it (note: untested!)

```
$('.edit_area').each(function(){
    $(this).editable($('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/edit_note_epreuve', {
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
        onblur : 'submit',
        submitdata : {  
             'user_id'       : $(this).closest('tr').data('user-id'),
             'id_epreuve'    : $('#id_epreuve').val(),
             '_token'        : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr( 'content' )
        },
        onerror : function(settings,original,xhr){
            alert("It wasn't possible to edit. Try again");
            console.log("XHR Status: " + xhr.status)} 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Honore, I have understood. I just tested it and it works fine. Thanks a lot, I was on this problem for 4 hours.

Comment: You ’re welcome, glad to help! There is a checkmark next to the answer you might find useful… =)